# SSMA hangs on connecting to microsoft access database

Tags: sql-server, ms-access

SQL Server Migration Assistant for access hangs after selecting MS Access database, it just shows 0% and nothing happens. Up to this point, everything worked fine, but after I configured encrypted connections on the server with a TLS certificate, for some reason starts to hang at 0%. At the same time, SQL Server Management Studio connects over an encrypted connection without issues and no other issues were[enter image description here noticed anymore.

Comment: When you configured the secure connection to SQL Server did you tick `TrustServerCertificate`? The SQL Server installer creates its own self-signed X.509 certificate for SQL Server instances by default. You either need to trust it with the `TrustServerCertificate` option, or export the server's public key portion to a .crt file to import into the Trusted Root Certificates store on the client computer or user performing the migration.

Comment: See also "For secure connection" paragraph in [Establishing a SQL Server Connection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssma/access/connecting-to-sql-server-accesstosql#establishing-a-sql-server-connection)

Comment: @AlwaysLearning Thanks for the answer. Yes I ticked TrustServerCertificate. And the connection to the server is established.
I did as written in this article [How To Issue SSL Certificate](https://sqldeep.com/how-to-issue-ssl-certificate-and-configure-microsoft-sql-server-to-use-issued-ssl-certificate/). And it looks like everything works. At least in SSMA, I establish a secure connection to the SQL server,
but when importing the Access Database into SSMA, it hangs at 0% and nothing happens. (See attached picture above)

Comment: The certificate that I created is trusted. And the certificate is located by trusted root certification authorities.

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps this information will help someone. I was able to solve my issue in the following way. I uninstall SSMA first, then uninstall Microsoft Access Database Engine 2016 Redistributable. Rebooted the machine, downloaded it again, and installed first SSMA then Microsoft Access Database Engine 2016 Redistributable.

Answer (score 0):

BTW, what I reported earlier was on a Windows 10 machine. Just tried on a Windows Server box and did not run into any problem. That Windows Server box had the most recent defender patch, a slightly different version of course. Version 1.343.352.0

Comment: Thank you. I know that it works, I tried it on another machine where there is no certificate, and everything works. But the machine with the certificate is installed does not work correctly. Most likely I made a mistake while creating the certificate and am trying to figure out what I did wrong.